# Why nginx won't work with base64 image in AJAX request (Laravel, Javascript, Nginx)

Tags: javascript, laravel, nginx

All other AJAX requests (signIn, SignUp, basicInformation, educationDetail etc) successfully done, but when I upload profile picture (base64) and send to laravel controller then nginx server doesn't work and return error...
I don't know where I missed something..
I increase upload file size and also increase buffer size but all time response same.
Please help me ...

*Cropped Image function in .js*

```
 jQuery('.cropped_image').on('click', function (ev) {           
    $image_crop.croppie('result', {
            type: 'canvas',
            size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function (response) {
        if(response != "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAD6CAYAAACI7Fo9AAAGBElEQVR4Xu3TAQEAAAjCMO1f2h5+NmDIjiNA4L3Avk8oIAECY+iegEBAwNADJYtIwND9AIGAgKEHShaRgKH7AQIBAUMPlCwiAUP3AwQCAoYeKFlEAobuBwgEBAw9ULKIBAzdDxAICBh6oGQRCRi6HyAQEDD0QMkiEjB0P0AgIGDogZJFJGDofoBAQMDQAyWLSMDQ/QCBgIChB0oWkYCh+wECAQFDD5QsIgFD9wMEAgKGHihZRAKG7gcIBAQMPVCyiAQM3Q8QCAgYeqBkEQkYuh8gEBAw9EDJIhIwdD9AICBg6IGSRSRg6H6AQEDA0AMli0jA0P0AgYCAoQdKFpGAofsBAgEBQw+ULCIBQ/cDBAIChh4oWUQChu4HCAQEDD1QsogEDN0PEAgIGHqgZBEJGLofIBAQMPRAySISMHQ/QCAgYOiBkkUkYOh+gEBAwNADJYtIwND9AIGAgKEHShaRgKH7AQIBAUMPlCwiAUP3AwQCAoYeKFlEAobuBwgEBAw9ULKIBAzdDxAICBh6oGQRCRi6HyAQEDD0QMkiEjB0P0AgIGDogZJFJGDofoBAQMDQAyWLSMDQ/QCBgIChB0oWkYCh+wECAQFDD5QsIgFD9wMEAgKGHihZRAKG7gcIBAQMPVCyiAQM3Q8QCAgYeqBkEQkYuh8gEBAw9EDJIhIwdD9AICBg6IGSRSRg6H6AQEDA0AMli0jA0P0AgYCAoQdKFpGAofsBAgEBQw+ULCIBQ/cDBAIChh4oWUQChu4HCAQEDD1QsogEDN0PEAgIGHqgZBEJGLofIBAQMPRAySISMHQ/QCAgYOiBkkUkYOh+gEBAwNADJYtIwND9AIGAgKEHShaRgKH7AQIBAUMPlCwiAUP3AwQCAoYeKFlEAobuBwgEBAw9ULKIBAzdDxAICBh6oGQRCRi6HyAQEDD0QMkiEjB0P0AgIGDogZJFJGDofoBAQMDQAyWLSMDQ/QCBgIChB0oWkYCh+wECAQFDD5QsIgFD9wMEAgKGHihZRAKG7gcIBAQMPVCyiAQM3Q8QCAgYeqBkEQkYuh8gEBAw9EDJIhIwdD9AICBg6IGSRSRg6H6AQEDA0AMli0jA0P0AgYCAoQdKFpGAofsBAgEBQw+ULCIBQ/cDBAIChh4oWUQChu4HCAQEDD1QsogEDN0PEAgIGHqgZBEJGLofIBAQMPRAySISMHQ/QCAgYOiBkkUkYOh+gEBAwNADJYtIwND9AIGAgKEHShaRgKH7AQIBAUMPlCwiAUP3AwQCAoYeKFlEAobuBwgEBAw9ULKIBAzdDxAICBh6oGQRCRi6HyAQEDD0QMkiEjB0P0AgIGDogZJFJGDofoBAQMDQAyWLSMDQ/QCBgIChB0oWkYCh+wECAQFDD5QsIgFD9wMEAgKGHihZRAKG7gcIBAQMPVCyiAQM3Q8QCAgYeqBkEQkYuh8gEBAw9EDJIhIwdD9AICBg6IGSRSRg6H6AQEDA0AMli0jA0P0AgYCAoQdKFpGAofsBAgEBQw+ULCIBQ/cDBAIChh4oWUQChu4HCAQEDD1QsogEDN0PEAgIGHqgZBEJGLofIBAQMPRAySISMHQ/QCAgYOiBkkUkYOh+gEBAwNADJYtIwND9AIGAgKEHShaRgKH7AQIBAUMPlCwiAUP3AwQCAoYeKFlEAobuBwgEBAw9ULKIBAzdDxAICBh6oGQRCRi6HyAQEDD0QMkiEjB0P0AgIGDogZJFJGDofoBAQMDQAyWLSMDQ/QCBgIChB0oWkYCh+wECAQFDD5QsIgFD9wMEAgKGHihZRAKG7gcIBAQMPVCyiAQM3Q8QCAgYeqBkEQkYuh8gEBAw9EDJIhIwdD9AICBg6IGSRSRg6H6AQEDA0AMli0jA0P0AgYCAoQdKFpGAofsBAgEBQw+ULCIBQ/cDBAIChh4oWUQChu4HCAQEDD1QsogEDN0PEAgIGHqgZBEJGLofIBAQMPRAySISMHQ/QCAgYOiBkkUkYOh+gEBAwNADJYtIwND9AIGAgKEHShaRgKH7AQIBAUMPlCwiAUP3AwQCAoYeKFlEAgcm/gD7Dx6GVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="){
            html = '<img id="croped-image-source" src="' + response + '" />';
            jQuery("#cropped-image-preview-section").html(html);
            profilePictureTemp = response;
            isPicSet = true;
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('profile_picture',response);
            jQuery.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/imag-store",
                data: data,
                cache: false, 
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                beforeSend: function () {
                    jQuery('#btn_submit').addClass('hidden');
                    jQuery('#loaderClass').removeClass('hidden');
                    console.log("Before Sending");
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(response);




                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    var msg = '';
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        msg = 'Time out error.';
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                    } else {
                        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                    }
                    jQuery('#btn_submit').removeClass('hidden');
                    jQuery('#loaderClass').addClass('hidden');
                    console.log(msg);
                }

            });
        }

    });
});
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/imag-store','ExpertInfoController@storeProfilePicture');
```

ExpertInfoController.php

```
 public function storeProfilePicture(Request $request){
$data = $request->get('experts_profile_picture'); 
if(substr($data, 11, strpos($data, ';')-11) == "png"){
  $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
 $data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
 $filename = 'experts_img'
               .rand()
                .'_'.time()
              .".png";

   $year = date("Y");
    $month = date("m");
    $path = PUBLIC_PATH_TO_STORE_IMAGE.'/images/experts/'.$year.'/'.$month.'';
     echo "Now entering create";
     echo ($path);

     $file = self::makeDirectory($path,0777,true,true);
      $file_path = $path.'/'.$filename;
      file_put_contents($file_path,base64_decode($data));
      $pic = str_replace(PUBLIC_PATH_TO_STORE_IMAGE,'',$file_path);
        }
        else{
            $pic = $request->get('experts_profile_picture');
        }
  $info = new ExpertInfo;
 $info->experts_profile_picture = $pic;
$info->save();
}
```

helloexperts.conf

```
server {
        client_max_body_size 20m;

        listen       80;

        server_name  helloexperts.dev;

        root        /var/www/vhosts/helloexperts.com/httpdocs/html/public;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
         add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        root         /var/www/vhosts/helloexperts.com/httpdocs/html/public;
        }
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        charset utf-8;


        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
#       #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';


  error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
location ~ \.php$ {
         root         /var/www/vhosts/helloexperts.com/httpdocs/html/public;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        #client_header_buffer_size 64k;
        #large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;


       fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;



        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 20M \n post_max_size = 20M";
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        include        fastcgi_params;
# add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }
 location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: 404 not found (all the time)

Comment: So the `storeProfilePicture()` method is causing the 404? If so, it is not the saving of the image that is causing the error. A 404 means not found. That means the controller method is unreachable. If the saving of the images was causing an error, it would probably be a 500 (internal server error).

Comment: actually its internal server error, but server return 404 for all type of errors.

Comment: AJAX request worked fine here when I store something other than image. Problem only occur when I upload image.

Comment: Have you tried if it goes wrong if you comment out the whole function body? Then piece by piece, remove the comments, see when it starts failing. Probably you have an error in your script somewhere then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm the route by doing

> php artisan route::list

. if the route does not exist try these commands .

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:cache
```

hope it helps. cheers!

**Update** i see the issue is in your code.you can use the following code to get the image from input . (i assume thats what you are trying to do)

```
$base64img = $request->input('image');

        if($base64img){
            // get the base-64 from data
            $file = substr($base64img, strpos($base64img ,",")+1);

            // decode base64 string
            $image = base64_decode($file); 

            $pos = strpos($base64img, ';');
            $imageType = explode('/', substr($base64img, 0, $pos))[1];
```

Comment: I checked route several times and also clear cache. Recently I checked a couple of min ago, image-store route exist with POST method.

Comment: This is working perfectly fine on localhost, only problem occur when I deploy project on nginx server...

Comment: can u ssh on your server and post the contents of laravel.log ?

Comment: you mentioned in your comment that image-store route exists whereas you are calling imag-store in your ajax request

Comment: ohh yeah, its typo

Comment: actually its imag-store

Comment: #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 122, Array)

Comment: looks like a permission issue to me can you run
chmod -R 777 [directory] on your project on server

Comment: Now its work fine, I change the ownership of nginx repository